# Filtering voice signal from randomly added frequencies

Tags: matlab, filters, filter-design, homework, voice

I have this assignment that I can't figure how to solve.

I have a sound.wav human-voice file, and use matlab add-random-noise (monotonic)

**Goal:** *to remove the noise from the sound (and the sound from the noise)*

What I've done so far is to read the file and then add the noise.
I then do an *fft*.
***Now I need to analyze the frequency spectrum, but I'm not sure how to do it.***
And finally do an *ifft* to recover the sound back.

I've used many kinds of filters: low pass, high pass, band pass, moving average.

The problems were:

1. I've managed to filter the sound without the noise BUT the sound always got worse as well.
2. It worked only for specific cases of random noise but not for any random noise that function might produce.

#### Any help would be appriciated. Thanks!

```
add_random_noise.m
    function yn=add_random_noise(y,Fs)
        n=[0:length(y)-1]';
        r=rand();
        %%rr=1+rand();
        %%rrr=2+2*rand();
        c=cos(2*pi*440*r*n/Fs);%%+cos(2*pi*440*rr*n/Fs)+cos(2*pi*440*rrr*n/Fs);
        yn=y+c/17;
        yn=yn/max(yn);
    end
```

include:
[add_random_noise.m](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_9WXGGn4j8ecnFQMm1YNTlLT28/edit?usp=sharing)
[sound.wav](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_9WXGGn4j8eeXZ3Z2l1LWVBY0U/edit?usp=sharing)

**EDIT:**

I have changed the add "noise" to return only one sinusoid noise.
I run the same noise with my original wav and with zeros and watched the noise in the peak in the range of the lower frequency

now i`m having truble to make the filter:
[matlab How to design lpf\bpf\hpf without builtin functions](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9365/matlab-how-to-design-lpf-bpf-hpf-without-builtin-functions)

Comment: Your noise is the sum of 3 sinusoids with random frequencies, right? This is a very specific situation. Haven't you treated some relevant methods in the course where the assignment is taken from? Do you need to remove the noise for one specific outcome of the random generator, or for all possible outcomes? This basically boils down to the question if the frequencies of the sinusoids can be viewed as fixed and known or not.

Comment: Matt. up till now I just thought to use the original voice and compare it with the noisy one. I'm not sure how can I benefit from this specific sinusoids noise equation. **the noise is unknown and I need to handle with all possible outcomes.** but before I can do that, help me to figure a simple one and I'll try my best for all the other random noises.

Comment: To begin with, go back to your teacher and insist that the sin waves can neither be considered random, nor can be termed `noise`. A better name for this function would be `add_random_frequencies`.

Comment: Then I assume that all you need to do is FFT the signal to identify frequencies whose average does not vary over time. Once found, just notch (filter) them out.

Comment: "whose average does not vary over time" what do you mean? I did compared between the original sound(_X_) to the noisy sound(_XN_) on the frequency domain (_dif=XN-X_). then I took the mean from _dif_, and then notch _NX_. the result is  a white noise and lower volume of the original sound. `avg = mean(abs(dif).^2)
for i = 1:length(dif)
 if abs(dif(i)).^2 > avg
  XN(i) = 0;
 end
end`

Comment: Are you allowed to use knowledge of the content of sound.wav?

Comment: I was wondering if you solved this issue.
I got an almost identical assignment and i have the same problem u did..
If you know the answer to your question please post it so i can learn from it. Thanks!

Comment: like izhaki said, by converting from time domain to frequency domain you can see the noise very clearly.
plot(abs(fft(yn)).^2) where yn is the sound or the noise.